# Advanced Search Using Custom Profile as Display View that Includes Groups Not Working after Upgrading to 5.9.0

Tags: profile, groups, search-results

After upgrading Civi from 5.3.1 to 5.9.0 (with drupal 7.61) any search results that use a custom display view (profile) does not work properly if that profile includes the groups or tags fields in the profile. Instead of the advanced search displaying all the records found it only displays one record at a time. At the top it may say "showing 1 to 50 of 100 records", but actually only shows one record.

I also hadn't realised that before upgrading, the groups or tags fields had not displayed at all in the advanced search - those columns would be missing even though they were included in the profile.

Is it possible to include groups or tags fields in a profile used for search results?

Disabling or deleting the groups/tags fields from the profile fixes the problem of only showing one contact at a time in the search results.

Screenshot attached

[image]

Comment: so is this question now "how can i get Group and Tags to display in Search Results via a Profile'?

Comment: sorry that the question was a little unclear. It was in two parts: yes, as you say, how can I get groups and tags to display in search results using a profile? And the second part was to report what seems like a bug: when groups and tags are added to search results profiles only one contact is displayed at a time

Comment: hmm i replicated on dmaster - so yes i guess it is a bug/missing feature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure the "1 row" problem only shows if you search using one custom Profile then switch to using a second custom Profile

Ie

Reset Form
then use Default, (all rows show)
then switch to profile with Groups field (all rows show)
then switch to profile with Tags field - **only 1 row shows**.

Reset Form
then use Default, (all rows show)
then switch to profile with Tags field (all rows show)
then switch to profile with Groups field - **only 1 row shows**.

So the problem seems to relate to switching between one custom search Profile and a second one.

NOTE: above came to light when trying to demo to Eileen that i could replicate https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/679

UPDATE: Fix at https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/13533

Comment: above came to light when trying to demo to Eileen that i could replicate https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/27913/advanced-search-using-custom-profile-as-display-view-that-includes-groups-not-wo

Comment: Many thanks Pete for your answer and the links. As a workaround I had removed all group/tag fields from my custom profiles used as views.